# Optimal transformation between two sets of points

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have two sets of points, in which each point is defined by a pair of (x, y) coordinates. The sets have the same number of points. Now I want to transform the first set of points to the second set, but the relationship of points in the two sets is unknown (which point is transformed into which). How do I find the optimal path for the all the points assuming all the points move in straight lines?

<s>There are two cases that could be considered:

1. minimizing the maximum path length.

2. minimizing the total path length.</s>

If the approaches are very different, consider only the first case where the maximum path length is minimized.

Comment: Do the sets have the same number of points? Can multiple source points map to the same target point? Do you measure the path length by the Euclidean distance of its corner points? The two variants are likely to require completely different approaches. Please choose one. You may post a second question for the other variant if you are interested in both.

Comment: So you basically have a *bipartite graph* and want to find an optimal *matching* (look up those).

Comment: @n.m. Thanks a lot. I found out that I could do a binary search on the maximum path length, exclude some of the paths, and see if it is possible to find a complete matching with the leftover paths.